# Construct query hangs in Fuseki Jena after executing 6 time

Tags: jena, fuseki

I am using Jena (version 3.10.0) with Fuseki(version 3.10.0) to test some construct queries but it hangs after running 6 queries. Below is my code. I am not sure if it is bug in Jena or I am doing something wrong. Select queries work fine. Will really appreciate if someone can help.

```java
    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        for(int i =0 ; i < 10;i++) {
            System.out.println(" ..... "+ i);
            String query = "CONSTRUCT {?S ?P ?O} WHERE {?S ?P ?O}";
            try(RDFConnectionFuseki connectFuseki = RDFConnectionFactory.connectFuseki("http://localhost:3030/test")) {
                System.out.println("Got connection!");
                org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model model = connectFuseki.queryConstruct(query);
                System.out.println("Executed query!");
                model.write(System.out, "TURTLE");
            }
       }
    }
```

Console output

```
     ..... 0
    Got connection!
    Executed query!
     ..... 1
    Got connection!
    Executed query!
     ..... 2
    Got connection!
    Executed query!
     ..... 3
    Got connection!
    Executed query!
     ..... 4
    Got connection!
    Executed query!
     ..... 5
    Got connection!
```

Comment: Is the data large (possibly Fuseki or your own code running out of memory)? Can you add System.out.println between the connectFuseki, queryConstruct and model.write lines to see on which of the three it hangs? If you cancel the hanging program and restart it, does it run six times again? Or does Fuseki need to be restarted too? And update your question with your findings?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Data is empty. I have added console output and it hangs  on `connectFuseki.queryConstruct(query)` . When it hangs I kill my test and can rerun it. But again it hangs. I do not restart Fuseki. I have tried it with inmem, persistent and TDB2 type repos and all of them hangs. Interestingly Select seems to be working fine.

Comment: Jena uses Apache HTTP Client which has an default limit of 5 open connections to a single host.  Normally this kind of hang is due to users not properly closing connections.  You're using an API I'm not particularly familiar with so maybe it isn't probably closing connections behind the scenes which would be a bug in Jena

Comment: Btw what version of Jena is this?

Comment: As @RobV says this might be a bug in Jena. Try `System.setProperty("http.maxConnections", 10)` to increase the open connection limit. If that works, then it's definitely a Jena bug. As a workaround, you could try `qe = connectFuseki.query(query)` to get a `QueryExecution` object, then call `qe.execConstruct()` to get your result, followed by `qe.close()` to explicitly close the connection.

Comment: Yeah I think the bug has been fixed [here](https://github.com/apache/jena/commit/a83373a780242a26e88c9843a33f7f6877e844bd) but that fix will only be in the next Jena release

Comment: @RobV Yeah it seems like a bug as I am creating connection within try which shoul close it. I am using `3.10.0` for both Jena and Fuseki.  @cygri I tried your suggestion `System.setProperty("http.maxConnections", 10)` and it now hangs when executing 10th query.

Comment: Just cloned master from Jena repo and it works. @RobV forgot to mention that `QueryExecution` has same problem as well. Thanks both. Will be good if you guys can add main answer as well.

Comment: This looks like JENA-1657 (fixed in the codebase).

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone else hits this issue I am adding the answer. As explained in the comments this is due to a bug and is fixed with [commit](https://github.com/apache/jena/commit/a83373a780242a26e88c9843a33f7f6877e844bd) so next release should fix this problem. In case you are stuck you can use [snapshot](https://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html) repo while waiting for the release.